# How to preset Blender shaders and textures?

Tags: texturing, shaders

In Blender, versions 2.79 and before default to the diffuse shader. In versions 2.80+, they default to Principled BSDF.

Even though this is a nice shader, is there a way that I can actually preset the shader Blender presets to when opening?

Same for textures: Is there a way that when I open Blender, I can have a preset texture?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite easy to do:

You can set up the .blend file that Blender default opens.

If I wanted to set up default shaders, I would simply go to the shaders tab, and select the shader I want to be the preset.
Same goes for the textures: go to the textures tab, and select the default Blender texture I would want to be the preset.

Now comes the magical part:

1) Save the .blend as (default.blend) or whatever.

2) Press <kbd>CTRL+U</kbd> to give you the "save startup file?" menu, and select it, or for the python-lovers' sake: 
`bpy.ops.wm.save_homefile()`.

3) Re-open Blender, and discover the new changes you have made.

This is how to preset default settings in Blender (not modifiers or unset simulators), and I hope it helps all that read this post!

Comment: It looks simple but it isn't! If you try to create a new material, you'll still get the principled node as default. It's hardwired in the source code.

Comment: You're right, but it is always good for other things. I.e. Starting with cycles default renderer.

Comment: But still not the correct answer to this question.. A solution would be to add a new material.new2 operator to startup/bl_operators, and change the all the original material.new calls to this new operator. It's not that easy, but doable.